# Using the default AccountController MVC5 with an existing Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-database-first

I have an existing database for which I have created a edmx file. Now I am trying to connect the default AccountController to this database and  implement login/registration functionalities but it doesnt work.

Things I tried -

I tried changing the context in the IdentityModels.cs.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("MyConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

Error  - The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Then, I tried this

```
    public partial class myEntities : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public myEntities ()
                : base("name=myEntities ")
            {
            }
    ... }
```

It dint work either.

1. Can someone help me with the steps involved in connecting my current
   database to the default account controller.
2. Should I create the tables in the database myself or will it be created ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need IdentityDbContext if you have decided to use EDMX? EDMX provides everything you need to work with existing database: connection string is in web.config, db context, all data entities and CRUD LINQ operations on them. In such case I would call them directly from any controller like this:

```
using (var myEntities = new MyEntities ())
{
        var users = from u in myEntities.Users
                       where u.id == 1
                       select u;
}
```

In such case your tables as well as database should exist otherwise you have to implement [code first approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4).